# Sum columns of dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I have dataframe with the following structure:

```
    structure(list(`Monday_04:00` = c(0, 0, 0), `Monday_04:15` = c(0, 
0, 0), `Monday_04:30` = c(0, 0, 0), `Monday_04:45` = c(0, 0, 
0), `Monday_05:00` = c(0, 0, 0), `Monday_05:15` = c(0, 0, 0), 
    `Monday_05:30` = c(0, 0, 0), `Monday_05:45` = c(0, 0, 0), 
    `Monday_06:00` = c(0, 0, 0), `Monday_06:15` = c(0, 0, 0), 
    `Monday_06:30` = c(0, 0, 0), `Monday_06:45` = c(0, 0, 0), 
    `Monday_07:00` = c(0, 0, 0), `Monday_07:15` = c(0, 0, 0), 
    `Monday_07:30` = c(0, 0, 0), `Monday_07:45` = c(0, 0, 0), 
    `Monday_08:00` = c(2, 0, 0), `Monday_08:15` = c(2, 0, 0), 
    `Monday_08:30` = c(2, 0, 0), `Monday_08:45` = c(2, 0, 0), 
    `Monday_09:00` = c(2, 0, 0), `Monday_09:15` = c(2, 0, 0), 
    `Monday_09:30` = c(2, 0, 0), `Monday_09:45` = c(2, 0, 0), 
    `Monday_10:00` = c(2, 0, 0), `Monday_10:15` = c(2, 0, 0), 
    `Monday_10:30` = c(2, 0, 0), `Monday_10:45` = c(2, 0, 0), 
    `Monday_11:00` = c(2, 0, 0), `Monday_11:15` = c(2, 0, 0), 
    `Monday_11:30` = c(2, 0, 0), `Monday_11:45` = c(2, 0, 0), 
    `Monday_12:00` = c(0, 0, 0), `Monday_12:15` = c(0, 0, 0), 
    `Monday_12:30` = c(0, 0, 0), `Monday_12:45` = c(0, 0, 0), 
    `Monday_13:00` = c(2, 0, 0), `Monday_13:15` = c(2, 0, 0), 
    `Monday_13:30` = c(2, 0, 0), `Monday_13:45` = c(2, 0, 0), 
    `Monday_14:00` = c(2, 0, 0), `Monday_14:15` = c(2, 0, 0), 
    `Monday_14:30` = c(2, 0, 0), `Monday_14:45` = c(2, 0, 0), 
    `Monday_15:00` = c(2, 0, 0), `Monday_15:15` = c(2, 0, 0), 
    `Monday_15:30` = c(2, 0, 0), `Monday_15:45` = c(2, 0, 0), 
    `Monday_16:00` = c(2, 0, 0), `Monday_16:15` = c(2, 0, 0), 
    `Monday_16:30` = c(2, 0, 0), `Monday_16:45` = c(2, 0, 0), 
    `Monday_17:00` = c(2, 0, 0), `Monday_17:15` = c(2, 0, 0), 
    `Monday_17:30` = c(2, 0, 0), `Monday_17:45` = c(2, 0, 0), 
    `Monday_18:00` = c(2, 0, 0), `Monday_18:15` = c(2, 0, 0), 
    `Monday_18:30` = c(0, 0, 0), `Monday_18:45` = c(0, 0, 0), 
    `Monday_19:00` = c(0, 0, 0), `Monday_19:15` = c(0, 0, 0), 
    `Monday_19:30` = c(0, 0, 0), `Monday_19:45` = c(0, 0, 0), 
    `Monday_20:00` = c(0, 0, 0), `Monday_20:15` = c(0, 0, 0), 
    `Monday_20:30` = c(0, 0, 0), `Monday_20:45` = c(0, 0, 0), 
    `Monday_21:00` = c(0, 0, 0), `Monday_21:15` = c(0, 0, 0), 
    `Monday_21:30` = c(0, 0, 0), `Monday_21:45` = c(0, 0, 0), 
    `Monday_22:00` = c(0, 0, 0), `Monday_22:15` = c(0, 0, 0), 
    `Monday_22:30` = c(0, 0, 0), `Monday_22:45` = c(0, 0, 0), 
    `Monday_23:00` = c(0, 0, 0), `Monday_23:15` = c(0, 0, 0), 
    `Monday_23:30` = c(0, 0, 0), `Monday_23:45` = c(0, 0, 0), 
    `Monday_00:00` = c(0, 0, 0), `Monday_00:15` = c(0, 0, 0), 
    `Monday_00:30` = c(0, 0, 0), `Monday_00:45` = c(0, 0, 0), 
    `Monday_01:00` = c(0, 0, 0), `Monday_01:15` = c(0, 0, 0), 
    `Monday_01:30` = c(0, 0, 0), `Monday_01:45` = c(0, 0, 0), 
    `Monday_02:00` = c(0, 0, 0), `Monday_02:15` = c(0, 0, 0), 
    `Monday_02:30` = c(0, 0, 0), `Monday_02:45` = c(0, 0, 0), 
    `Monday_03:00` = c(0, 0, 0), `Monday_03:15` = c(0, 0, 0), 
    `Monday_03:30` = c(0, 0, 0), `Monday_03:45` = c(0, 0, 0), 
    `Tuesday_04:00` = c(0, 0, 0), `Tuesday_04:15` = c(0, 0, 0
    ), `Tuesday_04:30` = c(0, 0, 0), `Tuesday_04:45` = c(0, 0, 
    0), `Tuesday_05:00` = c(0, 0, 0), `Tuesday_05:15` = c(0, 
    0, 0), `Tuesday_05:30` = c(0, 0, 0), `Tuesday_05:45` = c(0, 
    0, 0), `Tuesday_06:00` = c(0, 0, 0), `Tuesday_06:15` = c(0, 
    0, 0), `Tuesday_06:30` = c(0, 0, 0), `Tuesday_06:45` = c(0, 
    0, 0), `Tuesday_07:00` = c(0, 0, 0), `Tuesday_07:15` = c(0, 
    0, 0), `Tuesday_07:30` = c(0, 0, 0), `Tuesday_07:45` = c(0, 
    0, 0), `Tuesday_08:00` = c(2, 0, 0), `Tuesday_08:15` = c(2, 
    0, 0), `Tuesday_08:30` = c(2, 0, 2), `Tuesday_08:45` = c(2, 
    0, 2), `Tuesday_09:00` = c(2, 0, 2), `Tuesday_09:15` = c(2, 
    0, 2), `Tuesday_09:30` = c(2, 0, 2), `Tuesday_09:45` = c(2, 
    0, 2), `Tuesday_10:00` = c(2, 0, 2), `Tuesday_10:15` = c(2, 
    0, 2), `Tuesday_10:30` = c(2, 0, 2), `Tuesday_10:45` = c(2, 
    0, 2), `Tuesday_11:00` = c(2, 0, 2), `Tuesday_11:15` = c(2, 
    0, 2), `Tuesday_11:30` = c(2, 0, 2), `Tuesday_11:45` = c(2, 
    0, 2), `Tuesday_12:00` = c(0, 0, 2), `Tuesday_12:15` = c(0, 
    0, 2), `Tuesday_12:30` = c(0, 0, 2), `Tuesday_12:45` = c(0, 
    0, 2), `Tuesday_13:00` = c(2, 0, 2), `Tuesday_13:15` = c(2, 
    0, 2), `Tuesday_13:30` = c(2, 0, 2), `Tuesday_13:45` = c(2, 
    0, 2), `Tuesday_14:00` = c(2, 0, 2), `Tuesday_14:15` = c(2, 
    0, 2), `Tuesday_14:30` = c(2, 0, 2), `Tuesday_14:45` = c(2, 
    0, 2), `Tuesday_15:00` = c(2, 0, 2), `Tuesday_15:15` = c(2, 
    0, 2), `Tuesday_15:30` = c(2, 0, 2), `Tuesday_15:45` = c(2, 
    0, 0), `Tuesday_16:00` = c(2, 0, 0), `Tuesday_16:15` = c(2, 
    0, 0), `Tuesday_16:30` = c(2, 0, 0), `Tuesday_16:45` = c(2, 
    0, 0), `Tuesday_17:00` = c(2, 0, 0), `Tuesday_17:15` = c(2, 
    0, 0), `Tuesday_17:30` = c(2, 0, 0), `Tuesday_17:45` = c(2, 
    0, 0), `Tuesday_18:00` = c(2, 0, 0), `Tuesday_18:15` = c(2, 
    0, 0), `Tuesday_18:30` = c(0, 0, 0), `Tuesday_18:45` = c(0, 
    0, 0), `Tuesday_19:00` = c(0, 0, 0), `Tuesday_19:15` = c(0, 
    0, 0), `Tuesday_19:30` = c(0, 0, 0), `Tuesday_19:45` = c(0, 
    0, 0), `Tuesday_20:00` = c(0, 0, 0), `Tuesday_20:15` = c(0, 
    0, 0), `Tuesday_20:30` = c(0, 0, 0), `Tuesday_20:45` = c(0, 
    0, 0), `Tuesday_21:00` = c(0, 0, 0), `Tuesday_21:15` = c(0, 
    0, 0), `Tuesday_21:30` = c(0, 0, 0), `Tuesday_21:45` = c(0, 
    0, 0), `Tuesday_22:00` = c(0, 0, 0), `Tuesday_22:15` = c(0, 
    0, 0), `Tuesday_22:30` = c(0, 0, 0), `Tuesday_22:45` = c(0, 
    0, 0), `Tuesday_23:00` = c(0, 0, 0), `Tuesday_23:15` = c(0, 
    0, 0), `Tuesday_23:30` = c(0, 0, 0), `Tuesday_23:45` = c(0, 
    0, 0), `Tuesday_00:00` = c(0, 0, 0), `Tuesday_00:15` = c(0, 
    0, 0), `Tuesday_00:30` = c(0, 0, 0), `Tuesday_00:45` = c(0, 
    0, 0), `Tuesday_01:00` = c(0, 0, 0), `Tuesday_01:15` = c(0, 
    0, 0), `Tuesday_01:30` = c(0, 0, 0), `Tuesday_01:45` = c(0, 
    0, 0), `Tuesday_02:00` = c(0, 0, 0), `Tuesday_02:15` = c(0, 
    0, 0), `Tuesday_02:30` = c(0, 0, 0), `Tuesday_02:45` = c(0, 
    0, 0), `Tuesday_03:00` = c(0, 0, 0), `Tuesday_03:15` = c(0, 
    0, 0), `Tuesday_03:30` = c(0, 0, 0), `Tuesday_03:45` = c(0, 
    0, 0), `Wednesday_04:00` = c(0, 0, 0), `Wednesday_04:15` = c(0, 
    0, 0), `Wednesday_04:30` = c(0, 0, 0), `Wednesday_04:45` = c(0, 
    0, 0), `Wednesday_05:00` = c(0, 0, 0), `Wednesday_05:15` = c(0, 
    0, 0), `Wednesday_05:30` = c(0, 0, 0), `Wednesday_05:45` = c(0, 
    0, 0), `Wednesday_06:00` = c(0, 0, 0), `Wednesday_06:15` = c(0, 
    0, 0), `Wednesday_06:30` = c(0, 0, 0), `Wednesday_06:45` = c(0, 
    0, 0), `Wednesday_07:00` = c(0, 0, 0), `Wednesday_07:15` = c(0, 
    0, 0), `Wednesday_07:30` = c(0, 0, 0), `Wednesday_07:45` = c(0, 
    0, 0), `Wednesday_08:00` = c(0, 0, 2), `Wednesday_08:15` = c(0, 
    0, 2), `Wednesday_08:30` = c(0, 0, 2), `Wednesday_08:45` = c(0, 
    0, 2), `Wednesday_09:00` = c(0, 0, 2), `Wednesday_09:15` = c(0, 
    0, 2), `Wednesday_09:30` = c(0, 0, 2), `Wednesday_09:45` = c(0, 
    0, 2), `Wednesday_10:00` = c(0, 0, 2), `Wednesday_10:15` = c(0, 
    0, 2), `Wednesday_10:30` = c(0, 0, 2), `Wednesday_10:45` = c(0, 
    0, 2), `Wednesday_11:00` = c(0, 0, 2), `Wednesday_11:15` = c(0, 
    0, 2), `Wednesday_11:30` = c(0, 0, 2), `Wednesday_11:45` = c(0, 
    0, 2), `Wednesday_12:00` = c(0, 0, 2), `Wednesday_12:15` = c(0, 
    0, 2), `Wednesday_12:30` = c(0, 0, 2), `Wednesday_12:45` = c(0, 
    0, 2), `Wednesday_13:00` = c(0, 0, 2), `Wednesday_13:15` = c(0, 
    0, 2), `Wednesday_13:30` = c(0, 0, 2), `Wednesday_13:45` = c(0, 
    0, 2), `Wednesday_14:00` = c(0, 0, 2), `Wednesday_14:15` = c(0, 
    0, 2), `Wednesday_14:30` = c(0, 0, 2), `Wednesday_14:45` = c(0, 
    0, 2), `Wednesday_15:00` = c(0, 0, 2), `Wednesday_15:15` = c(0, 
    0, 2), `Wednesday_15:30` = c(0, 0, 2), `Wednesday_15:45` = c(0, 
    0, 2), `Wednesday_16:00` = c(0, 0, 2), `Wednesday_16:15` = c(0, 
    0, 2), `Wednesday_16:30` = c(0, 0, 2), `Wednesday_16:45` = c(0, 
    0, 2), `Wednesday_17:00` = c(0, 0, 2), `Wednesday_17:15` = c(0, 
    0, 2), `Wednesday_17:30` = c(0, 0, 0), `Wednesday_17:45` = c(0, 
    0, 0), `Wednesday_18:00` = c(0, 0, 0), `Wednesday_18:15` = c(0, 
    0, 0), `Wednesday_18:30` = c(0, 0, 0), `Wednesday_18:45` = c(0, 
    0, 0), `Wednesday_19:00` = c(0, 0, 0), `Wednesday_19:15` = c(0, 
    0, 0), `Wednesday_19:30` = c(0, 0, 0), `Wednesday_19:45` = c(0, 
    0, 0), `Wednesday_20:00` = c(0, 0, 0), `Wednesday_20:15` = c(0, 
    0, 0), `Wednesday_20:30` = c(0, 0, 0), `Wednesday_20:45` = c(0, 
    0, 0), `Wednesday_21:00` = c(0, 0, 0), `Wednesday_21:15` = c(0, 
    0, 0), `Wednesday_21:30` = c(0, 0, 0), `Wednesday_21:45` = c(0, 
    0, 0), `Wednesday_22:00` = c(0, 0, 0), `Wednesday_22:15` = c(0, 
    0, 0), `Wednesday_22:30` = c(0, 0, 0), `Wednesday_22:45` = c(0, 
    0, 0), `Wednesday_23:00` = c(0, 0, 0), `Wednesday_23:15` = c(0, 
    0, 0), `Wednesday_23:30` = c(0, 0, 0), `Wednesday_23:45` = c(0, 
    0, 0), `Wednesday_00:00` = c(0, 0, 0), `Wednesday_00:15` = c(0, 
    0, 0), `Wednesday_00:30` = c(0, 0, 0), `Wednesday_00:45` = c(0, 
    0, 0), `Wednesday_01:00` = c(0, 0, 0), `Wednesday_01:15` = c(0, 
    0, 0), `Wednesday_01:30` = c(0, 0, 0), `Wednesday_01:45` = c(0, 
    0, 0), `Wednesday_02:00` = c(0, 0, 0), `Wednesday_02:15` = c(0, 
    0, 0), `Wednesday_02:30` = c(0, 0, 0), `Wednesday_02:45` = c(0, 
    0, 0), `Wednesday_03:00` = c(0, 0, 0), `Wednesday_03:15` = c(0, 
    0, 0), `Wednesday_03:30` = c(0, 0, 0), `Wednesday_03:45` = c(0, 
    0, 0), `Thursday_04:00` = c(0, 0, 0), `Thursday_04:15` = c(0, 
    0, 0), `Thursday_04:30` = c(0, 0, 0), `Thursday_04:45` = c(0, 
    0, 0), `Thursday_05:00` = c(0, 0, 0), `Thursday_05:15` = c(0, 
    0, 0), `Thursday_05:30` = c(0, 0, 0), `Thursday_05:45` = c(0, 
    0, 0), `Thursday_06:00` = c(0, 0, 0), `Thursday_06:15` = c(0, 
    0, 0), `Thursday_06:30` = c(0, 0, 0), `Thursday_06:45` = c(0, 
    0, 0), `Thursday_07:00` = c(0, 0, 0), `Thursday_07:15` = c(0, 
    0, 0), `Thursday_07:30` = c(0, 0, 0), `Thursday_07:45` = c(0, 
    0, 0), `Thursday_08:00` = c(0, 0, 0), `Thursday_08:15` = c(0, 
    0, 0), `Thursday_08:30` = c(0, 0, 2), `Thursday_08:45` = c(0, 
    0, 2), `Thursday_09:00` = c(0, 0, 2), `Thursday_09:15` = c(0, 
    0, 2), `Thursday_09:30` = c(0, 0, 2), `Thursday_09:45` = c(0, 
    0, 2), `Thursday_10:00` = c(0, 0, 2), `Thursday_10:15` = c(0, 
    0, 2), `Thursday_10:30` = c(0, 0, 2), `Thursday_10:45` = c(0, 
    0, 2), `Thursday_11:00` = c(0, 0, 2), `Thursday_11:15` = c(0, 
    0, 2), `Thursday_11:30` = c(0, 0, 2), `Thursday_11:45` = c(0, 
    0, 2), `Thursday_12:00` = c(0, 0, 2), `Thursday_12:15` = c(0, 
    0, 2), `Thursday_12:30` = c(0, 0, 2), `Thursday_12:45` = c(0, 
    0, 2), `Thursday_13:00` = c(0, 0, 2), `Thursday_13:15` = c(0, 
    0, 2), `Thursday_13:30` = c(0, 0, 2), `Thursday_13:45` = c(0, 
    0, 2), `Thursday_14:00` = c(0, 0, 2), `Thursday_14:15` = c(0, 
    0, 2), `Thursday_14:30` = c(0, 0, 2), `Thursday_14:45` = c(0, 
    0, 2), `Thursday_15:00` = c(0, 0, 2), `Thursday_15:15` = c(0, 
    0, 2), `Thursday_15:30` = c(0, 0, 2), `Thursday_15:45` = c(0, 
    0, 2), `Thursday_16:00` = c(0, 0, 2), `Thursday_16:15` = c(0, 
    0, 2), `Thursday_16:30` = c(0, 0, 2), `Thursday_16:45` = c(0, 
    0, 2), `Thursday_17:00` = c(0, 0, 0), `Thursday_17:15` = c(0, 
    0, 0), `Thursday_17:30` = c(0, 0, 0), `Thursday_17:45` = c(0, 
    0, 0), `Thursday_18:00` = c(0, 0, 0), `Thursday_18:15` = c(0, 
    0, 0), `Thursday_18:30` = c(0, 0, 0), `Thursday_18:45` = c(0, 
    0, 0), `Thursday_19:00` = c(0, 0, 0), `Thursday_19:15` = c(0, 
    0, 0), `Thursday_19:30` = c(0, 0, 0), `Thursday_19:45` = c(0, 
    0, 0), `Thursday_20:00` = c(0, 0, 0), `Thursday_20:15` = c(0, 
    0, 0), `Thursday_20:30` = c(0, 0, 0), `Thursday_20:45` = c(0, 
    0, 0), `Thursday_21:00` = c(0, 0, 0), `Thursday_21:15` = c(0, 
    0, 0), `Thursday_21:30` = c(0, 0, 0), `Thursday_21:45` = c(0, 
    0, 0), `Thursday_22:00` = c(0, 0, 0), `Thursday_22:15` = c(0, 
    0, 0), `Thursday_22:30` = c(0, 0, 0), `Thursday_22:45` = c(0, 
    0, 0), `Thursday_23:00` = c(0, 0, 0), `Thursday_23:15` = c(0, 
    0, 0), `Thursday_23:30` = c(0, 0, 0), `Thursday_23:45` = c(0, 
    0, 0), `Thursday_00:00` = c(0, 0, 0), `Thursday_00:15` = c(0, 
    0, 0), `Thursday_00:30` = c(0, 0, 0), `Thursday_00:45` = c(0, 
    0, 0), `Thursday_01:00` = c(0, 0, 0), `Thursday_01:15` = c(0, 
    0, 0), `Thursday_01:30` = c(0, 0, 0), `Thursday_01:45` = c(0, 
    0, 0), `Thursday_02:00` = c(0, 0, 0), `Thursday_02:15` = c(0, 
    0, 0), `Thursday_02:30` = c(0, 0, 0), `Thursday_02:45` = c(0, 
    0, 0), `Thursday_03:00` = c(0, 0, 0), `Thursday_03:15` = c(0, 
    0, 0), `Thursday_03:30` = c(0, 0, 0), `Thursday_03:45` = c(0, 
    0, 0), `Friday_04:00` = c(0, 0, 0), `Friday_04:15` = c(0, 
    0, 0), `Friday_04:30` = c(0, 0, 0), `Friday_04:45` = c(0, 
    0, 0), `Friday_05:00` = c(0, 0, 0), `Friday_05:15` = c(0, 
    0, 0), `Friday_05:30` = c(0, 0, 0), `Friday_05:45` = c(0, 
    0, 0), `Friday_06:00` = c(0, 0, 0), `Friday_06:15` = c(0, 
    0, 0), `Friday_06:30` = c(0, 0, 0), `Friday_06:45` = c(0, 
    0, 0), `Friday_07:00` = c(0, 0, 0), `Friday_07:15` = c(0, 
    0, 0), `Friday_07:30` = c(0, 0, 0), `Friday_07:45` = c(0, 
    0, 0), `Friday_08:00` = c(0, 0, 0), `Friday_08:15` = c(2, 
    0, 0), `Friday_08:30` = c(2, 0, 2), `Friday_08:45` = c(2, 
    0, 2), `Friday_09:00` = c(2, 0, 2), `Friday_09:15` = c(2, 
    0, 2), `Friday_09:30` = c(2, 0, 2), `Friday_09:45` = c(2, 
    0, 2), `Friday_10:00` = c(2, 0, 2), `Friday_10:15` = c(2, 
    0, 2), `Friday_10:30` = c(2, 0, 2), `Friday_10:45` = c(2, 
    0, 2), `Friday_11:00` = c(2, 0, 2), `Friday_11:15` = c(2, 
    0, 2), `Friday_11:30` = c(2, 0, 0), `Friday_11:45` = c(2, 
    0, 0), `Friday_12:00` = c(0, 0, 0), `Friday_12:15` = c(0, 
    0, 0), `Friday_12:30` = c(0, 0, 0), `Friday_12:45` = c(0, 
    0, 0), `Friday_13:00` = c(0, 0, 0), `Friday_13:15` = c(2, 
    0, 0), `Friday_13:30` = c(2, 0, 0), `Friday_13:45` = c(2, 
    0, 0), `Friday_14:00` = c(2, 0, 0), `Friday_14:15` = c(2, 
    0, 0), `Friday_14:30` = c(2, 2, 0), `Friday_14:45` = c(2, 
    2, 0), `Friday_15:00` = c(2, 2, 0), `Friday_15:15` = c(2, 
    2, 0), `Friday_15:30` = c(2, 2, 0), `Friday_15:45` = c(2, 
    2, 0), `Friday_16:00` = c(2, 2, 0), `Friday_16:15` = c(2, 
    2, 0), `Friday_16:30` = c(2, 2, 0), `Friday_16:45` = c(2, 
    2, 0), `Friday_17:00` = c(2, 2, 0), `Friday_17:15` = c(2, 
    2, 0), `Friday_17:30` = c(2, 2, 0), `Friday_17:45` = c(2, 
    2, 0), `Friday_18:00` = c(2, 2, 0), `Friday_18:15` = c(0, 
    2, 0), `Friday_18:30` = c(0, 2, 0), `Friday_18:45` = c(0, 
    2, 0), `Friday_19:00` = c(0, 2, 0), `Friday_19:15` = c(0, 
    2, 0), `Friday_19:30` = c(0, 0, 0), `Friday_19:45` = c(0, 
    0, 0), `Friday_20:00` = c(0, 0, 0), `Friday_20:15` = c(0, 
    0, 0), `Friday_20:30` = c(0, 0, 0), `Friday_20:45` = c(0, 
    0, 0), `Friday_21:00` = c(0, 0, 0), `Friday_21:15` = c(0, 
    0, 0), `Friday_21:30` = c(0, 0, 0), `Friday_21:45` = c(0, 
    0, 0), `Friday_22:00` = c(0, 0, 0), `Friday_22:15` = c(0, 
    0, 0), `Friday_22:30` = c(0, 0, 0), `Friday_22:45` = c(0, 
    0, 0), `Friday_23:00` = c(0, 0, 0), `Friday_23:15` = c(0, 
    0, 0), `Friday_23:30` = c(0, 0, 0), `Friday_23:45` = c(0, 
    0, 0), `Friday_00:00` = c(0, 0, 0), `Friday_00:15` = c(0, 
    0, 0), `Friday_00:30` = c(0, 0, 0), `Friday_00:45` = c(0, 
    0, 0), `Friday_01:00` = c(0, 0, 0), `Friday_01:15` = c(0, 
    0, 0), `Friday_01:30` = c(0, 0, 0), `Friday_01:45` = c(0, 
    0, 0), `Friday_02:00` = c(0, 0, 0), `Friday_02:15` = c(0, 
    0, 0), `Friday_02:30` = c(0, 0, 0), `Friday_02:45` = c(0, 
    0, 0), `Friday_03:00` = c(0, 0, 0), `Friday_03:15` = c(0, 
    0, 0), `Friday_03:30` = c(0, 0, 0), `Friday_03:45` = c(0, 
    0, 0), `Saturday_04:00` = c(0, 0, 0), `Saturday_04:15` = c(0, 
    0, 0), `Saturday_04:30` = c(0, 0, 0), `Saturday_04:45` = c(0, 
    0, 0), `Saturday_05:00` = c(0, 0, 0), `Saturday_05:15` = c(0, 
    0, 0), `Saturday_05:30` = c(0, 0, 0), `Saturday_05:45` = c(0, 
    0, 0), `Saturday_06:00` = c(0, 0, 0), `Saturday_06:15` = c(0, 
    0, 0), `Saturday_06:30` = c(0, 0, 0), `Saturday_06:45` = c(0, 
    0, 0), `Saturday_07:00` = c(0, 0, 0), `Saturday_07:15` = c(0, 
    0, 0), `Saturday_07:30` = c(0, 0, 0), `Saturday_07:45` = c(0, 
    0, 0), `Saturday_08:00` = c(0, 0, 0), `Saturday_08:15` = c(2, 
    0, 0), `Saturday_08:30` = c(2, 0, 0), `Saturday_08:45` = c(2, 
    0, 0), `Saturday_09:00` = c(2, 0, 0), `Saturday_09:15` = c(2, 
    0, 0), `Saturday_09:30` = c(2, 0, 0), `Saturday_09:45` = c(2, 
    0, 0), `Saturday_10:00` = c(2, 0, 0), `Saturday_10:15` = c(2, 
    0, 0), `Saturday_10:30` = c(2, 0, 0), `Saturday_10:45` = c(2, 
    0, 0), `Saturday_11:00` = c(2, 0, 0), `Saturday_11:15` = c(2, 
    0, 0), `Saturday_11:30` = c(2, 0, 0), `Saturday_11:45` = c(2, 
    0, 0), `Saturday_12:00` = c(0, 0, 0), `Saturday_12:15` = c(0, 
    0, 0), `Saturday_12:30` = c(0, 0, 0), `Saturday_12:45` = c(0, 
    0, 0), `Saturday_13:00` = c(2, 0, 0), `Saturday_13:15` = c(2, 
    0, 0), `Saturday_13:30` = c(2, 0, 0), `Saturday_13:45` = c(2, 
    0, 0), `Saturday_14:00` = c(2, 0, 0), `Saturday_14:15` = c(2, 
    0, 0), `Saturday_14:30` = c(2, 0, 0), `Saturday_14:45` = c(2, 
    0, 0), `Saturday_15:00` = c(2, 0, 0), `Saturday_15:15` = c(2, 
    0, 0), `Saturday_15:30` = c(2, 0, 0), `Saturday_15:45` = c(2, 
    0, 0), `Saturday_16:00` = c(2, 0, 0), `Saturday_16:15` = c(2, 
    0, 0), `Saturday_16:30` = c(2, 0, 0), `Saturday_16:45` = c(2, 
    0, 0), `Saturday_17:00` = c(2, 0, 0), `Saturday_17:15` = c(2, 
    0, 0), `Saturday_17:30` = c(2, 0, 0), `Saturday_17:45` = c(2, 
    0, 0), `Saturday_18:00` = c(2, 0, 0), `Saturday_18:15` = c(0, 
    0, 0), `Saturday_18:30` = c(0, 0, 0), `Saturday_18:45` = c(0, 
    0, 0), `Saturday_19:00` = c(0, 0, 0), `Saturday_19:15` = c(0, 
    0, 0), `Saturday_19:30` = c(0, 0, 0), `Saturday_19:45` = c(0, 
    0, 0), `Saturday_20:00` = c(0, 0, 0), `Saturday_20:15` = c(0, 
    0, 0), `Saturday_20:30` = c(0, 0, 0), `Saturday_20:45` = c(0, 
    0, 0), `Saturday_21:00` = c(0, 0, 0), `Saturday_21:15` = c(0, 
    0, 0), `Saturday_21:30` = c(0, 0, 0), `Saturday_21:45` = c(0, 
    0, 0), `Saturday_22:00` = c(0, 0, 0), `Saturday_22:15` = c(0, 
    0, 0), `Saturday_22:30` = c(0, 0, 0), `Saturday_22:45` = c(0, 
    0, 0), `Saturday_23:00` = c(0, 0, 0), `Saturday_23:15` = c(0, 
    0, 0), `Saturday_23:30` = c(0, 0, 0), `Saturday_23:45` = c(0, 
    0, 0), `Saturday_00:00` = c(0, 0, 0), `Saturday_00:15` = c(0, 
    0, 0), `Saturday_00:30` = c(0, 0, 0), `Saturday_00:45` = c(0, 
    0, 0), `Saturday_01:00` = c(0, 0, 0), `Saturday_01:15` = c(0, 
    0, 0), `Saturday_01:30` = c(0, 0, 0), `Saturday_01:45` = c(0, 
    0, 0), `Saturday_02:00` = c(0, 0, 0), `Saturday_02:15` = c(0, 
    0, 0), `Saturday_02:30` = c(0, 0, 0), `Saturday_02:45` = c(0, 
    0, 0), `Saturday_03:00` = c(0, 0, 0), `Saturday_03:15` = c(0, 
    0, 0), `Saturday_03:30` = c(0, 0, 0), `Saturday_03:45` = c(0, 
    0, 0), `Sunday_04:00` = c(0, 0, 0), `Sunday_04:15` = c(0, 
    0, 0), `Sunday_04:30` = c(0, 0, 0), `Sunday_04:45` = c(0, 
    0, 0), `Sunday_05:00` = c(0, 0, 0), `Sunday_05:15` = c(0, 
    0, 0), `Sunday_05:30` = c(0, 0, 0), `Sunday_05:45` = c(0, 
    0, 0), `Sunday_06:00` = c(0, 0, 0), `Sunday_06:15` = c(0, 
    0, 0), `Sunday_06:30` = c(0, 0, 0), `Sunday_06:45` = c(0, 
    0, 0), `Sunday_07:00` = c(0, 0, 0), `Sunday_07:15` = c(0, 
    0, 0), `Sunday_07:30` = c(0, 0, 0), `Sunday_07:45` = c(0, 
    0, 0), `Sunday_08:00` = c(2, 0, 0), `Sunday_08:15` = c(2, 
    0, 0), `Sunday_08:30` = c(2, 0, 0), `Sunday_08:45` = c(2, 
    0, 0), `Sunday_09:00` = c(2, 0, 0), `Sunday_09:15` = c(2, 
    0, 0), `Sunday_09:30` = c(2, 0, 0), `Sunday_09:45` = c(2, 
    0, 0), `Sunday_10:00` = c(2, 0, 0), `Sunday_10:15` = c(2, 
    0, 0), `Sunday_10:30` = c(2, 0, 0), `Sunday_10:45` = c(2, 
    0, 0), `Sunday_11:00` = c(2, 0, 0), `Sunday_11:15` = c(2, 
    0, 0), `Sunday_11:30` = c(2, 0, 0), `Sunday_11:45` = c(2, 
    0, 0), `Sunday_12:00` = c(2, 0, 0), `Sunday_12:15` = c(2, 
    0, 0), `Sunday_12:30` = c(2, 0, 0), `Sunday_12:45` = c(2, 
    0, 0), `Sunday_13:00` = c(0, 0, 0), `Sunday_13:15` = c(0, 
    0, 0), `Sunday_13:30` = c(0, 0, 0), `Sunday_13:45` = c(0, 
    0, 0), `Sunday_14:00` = c(2, 0, 0), `Sunday_14:15` = c(2, 
    0, 0), `Sunday_14:30` = c(2, 0, 0), `Sunday_14:45` = c(2, 
    0, 0), `Sunday_15:00` = c(2, 0, 0), `Sunday_15:15` = c(2, 
    0, 0), `Sunday_15:30` = c(2, 0, 0), `Sunday_15:45` = c(2, 
    0, 0), `Sunday_16:00` = c(2, 0, 0), `Sunday_16:15` = c(2, 
    0, 0), `Sunday_16:30` = c(2, 0, 0), `Sunday_16:45` = c(2, 
    0, 0), `Sunday_17:00` = c(2, 0, 0), `Sunday_17:15` = c(2, 
    0, 0), `Sunday_17:30` = c(0, 0, 0), `Sunday_17:45` = c(0, 
    0, 0), `Sunday_18:00` = c(0, 0, 0), `Sunday_18:15` = c(0, 
    0, 0), `Sunday_18:30` = c(0, 0, 0), `Sunday_18:45` = c(0, 
    0, 0), `Sunday_19:00` = c(0, 0, 0), `Sunday_19:15` = c(0, 
    0, 0), `Sunday_19:30` = c(0, 0, 0), `Sunday_19:45` = c(0, 
    0, 0), `Sunday_20:00` = c(0, 0, 0), `Sunday_20:15` = c(0, 
    0, 0), `Sunday_20:30` = c(0, 0, 0), `Sunday_20:45` = c(0, 
    0, 0), `Sunday_21:00` = c(0, 0, 0), `Sunday_21:15` = c(0, 
    0, 0), `Sunday_21:30` = c(0, 0, 0), `Sunday_21:45` = c(0, 
    0, 0), `Sunday_22:00` = c(0, 0, 0), `Sunday_22:15` = c(0, 
    0, 0), `Sunday_22:30` = c(0, 0, 0), `Sunday_22:45` = c(0, 
    0, 0), `Sunday_23:00` = c(0, 0, 0), `Sunday_23:15` = c(0, 
    0, 0), `Sunday_23:30` = c(0, 0, 0), `Sunday_23:45` = c(0, 
    0, 0), `Sunday_00:00` = c(0, 0, 0), `Sunday_00:15` = c(0, 
    0, 0), `Sunday_00:30` = c(0, 0, 0), `Sunday_00:45` = c(0, 
    0, 0), `Sunday_01:00` = c(0, 0, 0), `Sunday_01:15` = c(0, 
    0, 0), `Sunday_01:30` = c(0, 0, 0), `Sunday_01:45` = c(0, 
    0, 0), `Sunday_02:00` = c(0, 0, 0), `Sunday_02:15` = c(0, 
    0, 0), `Sunday_02:30` = c(0, 0, 0), `Sunday_02:45` = c(0, 
    0, 0), `Sunday_03:00` = c(0, 0, 0), `Sunday_03:15` = c(0, 
    0, 0), `Sunday_03:30` = c(0, 0, 0), `Sunday_03:45` = c(0, 
    0, 0), index = 1:3), row.names = c(NA, 3L), class = "data.frame")
>
```

The first row (rn)contains numbers from 2 to 3523. The other 672 columns are time steps that record people works chedules: 0 - not worked and 2 - worked

I am trying to calculate: a.)  daily workhours per id (sum of 95 columns/day).
                          b.)  weekly workhours per id

Any suggestion is welcomed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use `tidyr` and `dplyr` to go from wide to long format and then `group_by` and `summarize`.

Try this:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  gather(day_time, worked, -index) %>% 
  separate(day_time, c("day", "time"), "_") %>% 
  group_by(index, day) %>%
  summarize(tot_work = sum(worked)/2*15/60) 
#> # A tibble: 21 x 3
#> # Groups:   index [?]
#>    index day       tot_work
#>    <int> <chr>        <dbl>
#>  1     1 Friday        8.75
#>  2     1 Monday        9.5 
#>  3     1 Saturday      9   
#>  4     1 Sunday        8.5 
#>  5     1 Thursday      0   
#>  6     1 Tuesday       9.5 
#>  7     1 Wednesday     0   
#>  8     2 Friday        5   
#>  9     2 Monday        0   
#> 10     2 Saturday      0   
#> # … with 11 more rows


df %>% 
  gather(day_time, worked, -index) %>% 
  separate(day_time, c("day", "time"), "_") %>% 
  group_by(index) %>%
  summarize(tot_work = sum(worked)/2 * 15 / 60) # divided by 2 * 15 min and divided by 60 min to have everything in hours
#> # A tibble: 3 x 2
#>   index tot_work
#>   <int>    <dbl>
#> 1     1     45.2
#> 2     2      5  
#> 3     3     28.2
```

If you want everything in minutes do not divide by 60.

Answer (score 1):

Consider reshaping your data from the current wide format to long format. This is the ideal structure for most data analytics including aggregation and a storage efficient format as columns necessitate more meta data (i.e., tracking types) than rows.

```
# RESHAPE WIDE TO LONG
rdf <- reshape(df, idvar="index", varying=list(head(names(df),-1)), v.names="hours",
               times = head(names(df),-1), timevar = "day_time",
               new.row.names = 1:1E5, direction = "long")

# SPLIT DAY AND TIME
rdf[c("day", "time")] <- t(sapply(strsplit(rdf$day_time, split="_"), "["))
rdf$day_time <- NULL

head(rdf, 10)
#    index hours    day  time
# 1      1     0 Monday 04:00
# 2      2     0 Monday 04:00
# 3      3     0 Monday 04:00
# 4      1     0 Monday 04:15
# 5      2     0 Monday 04:15
# 6      3     0 Monday 04:15
# 7      1     0 Monday 04:30
# 8      2     0 Monday 04:30
# 9      3     0 Monday 04:30
# 10     1     0 Monday 04:45

# SUMMARIZE HOURS BY INDEX
agg_df <- aggregate(hours ~ index, rdf, sum)
agg_df

#   index hours
# 1     1   362
# 2     2    40
# 3     3   226
```

By weekday:

```
rdf$day <- factor(rdf$day, levels=c("Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", 
                                    "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"))

aggregate(hours ~ index + day, rdf, sum)
#          day index hours
# 1     Monday     1    76
# 2    Tuesday     1    76
# 3  Wednesday     1     0
# 4   Thursday     1     0
# 5     Friday     1    70
# 6   Saturday     1    72
# 7     Sunday     1    68
# 8     Monday     2     0
# 9    Tuesday     2     0
# 10 Wednesday     2     0
# 11  Thursday     2     0
# 12    Friday     2    40
# 13  Saturday     2     0
# 14    Sunday     2     0
# 15    Monday     3     0
# 16   Tuesday     3    58
# 17 Wednesday     3    76
# 18  Thursday     3    68
# 19    Friday     3    24
# 20  Saturday     3     0
# 21    Sunday     3     0
```